# Inserting data from one table to another repeatedly according to qnty value

Tags: asp.net

I have two tables table1 and table2. I need to insert table values from table1 to table2. The table 1 contain columns nnum,code,qnty and table2 also same column. I need to insert table1 value to table2 and repeat the insertion according to the qnty value.But my current code is not working properly. Here I am attaching the format I need to get. The Table2 in the image is the thing I need to get.

```
 protected void Button15_Click3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection ;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            connetionString = "Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into Table2(Code, Model, Num, Qty) select Code, Model, Num, Qty from Table1", connection);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                connection.Close();

                String str2 = "select * from Table2;";
                SqlCommand xp2 = new SqlCommand(str2, con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da2.SelectCommand = xp2;
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(ds2, "Table2");
                con.Close();

                    for (i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Qty"].ToString()) ; i++)
                    {
                        String str1 = "insert into Table2(Code, Model, Num, Qty) select Code, Model, Num, Qty from Table1;";
                        SqlCommand xp1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);

                        con.Open();
                        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        da1.SelectCommand = xp1;
                        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                        da1.Fill(ds1, "Code");
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
                        con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
```

}
   [image]

Comment: you have to rewrite the whole thing, as for now you are inserting the whole table1 into table2 for each iteration depending on qty+1

Comment: I didnt get u,could u pls explain

Comment: insert into table1(...)  select * from table2  , will insert ALL rows from table2 into table1... and you do that in a for loop qty + 1 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use procedure method in sql program or use javascript in program